# Which sentence is better grammatically?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, meaning-in-context, prepositions

1. I would like to have fewer classes on Friday than on any other day.
2. I would like to have fewer classes on Friday than any other day.

Is it redundant to use *"on"* twice?

Comment: I's entirely a stylistic choice. And [here's a usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=than+any+other+day%2Cthan+on+any+other+day&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthan%20any%20other%20day%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthan%20on%20any%20other%20day%3B%2Cc0) showing that writers have chosen both versions about equally often for centuries (but with a possibly-significant shift in favour of ***not*** including the preposition, in recent decades).

Comment: Welcome to this site. Your question might be better answered in the English Language Learners site.

Comment: Already addressed on ELL at [What happens to an adverbial preposition-phrase such as 
 'on Monday' when you remove the preposition?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/478034/what-happens-to-an-adverbial-preposition-phrase-such-as-on-monday-when-you-rem)

Comment: No need to say "any other day". Since you already emphasize the day, which is Friday, it already excludes other days of the week. So, simply "I would like to have fewer classes on Friday." is just enough.

Answer (score -1):

In fact, the first sentence "I would like to have fewer classes on Friday than on any other day." is better. It is ok to use "on" twice.
The second sentence "I would like to have fewer classes on Friday than any other day." sounds strange, so we don't usually say that.

BTW, it should be: I would like to have fewer classes on Friday than any other day"s"

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: No, I don't think it should be. More importantly: can you explain *why* you suggest what you suggest?

Comment: We usually use the preposition "on" before days, such as Monday, Tuesday, or Sunday.
Of course, it's still ok to use the second one, but the first sentence is obviously better.

Comment: I'd say on-deletion here is more prevalent in the States than in the UK. Even the first one is a candidate for deletion. And perhaps deleting or keeping both gives better balance.